# Jenkins pipeline does not run strapi start command?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, strapi

I wrote a jenkins pipeline that check out the git repo code and do the npm install command and strapi start command . But when it execute strapi start it shows error like  "**(node:12501) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'dev_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**" . I does not know why it happens but it successfully completed the npm install command. Any help. This is stage I am getting error.

```
stage('Install all dependencies and start'){
            echo 'INFO - Starting installing the package.json file'
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'strapi start'


        }
```

Thank you

Comment: can you share the script ?

Comment: its ssh to production server then install `strapi`, right ? has `strapi` tool installed on production server, yet ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes strapi tool was installed on the production server.

Comment: did you `strapi new my-project` for create new project ? as its https://github.com/strapi/strapi

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes I followed this everything. But when I run in jenkins then only it shows me that problem. In my local it is running properly. My jenkins was running on separate server.

Comment: if you follow the link,  please update the question.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Why you delete your answer.

Comment: please update the question first, because you said, "Yes I followed this everything" ? but still got error

Comment: Run with npm: `npm run start` or node itself: `node path/to/your/server.js`

Comment: @Ariel Still remains same error. Whether I want to give any permission to jenkins to access that, because it shows "(node:3864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'dev_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: @Prakash perhaps it's running in the wrong environment? Or the environment it's not configured the correct way, maybe something misspelled? For what I can see Strapi is trying to start but the db connection seems to fail.

Comment: @Ariel you are correct. I resolved this issue.

Comment: @Prakash glad you got it working! Please post your solution (as an Answer) here and accept it :)